# How do I call a class function from within an object within the class?

Tags: objective-c, xcode

Basically, I want to call a function of a main class within a subclass that the main class holds a pointer to.
I know I can just get the main class to initiate the subclass and attach the function to it. But I do not want that, I want the subclass to initiate itself with its init function.
**Is there any way I can call doSomething from someClass?**
Some basic code to show what I want:
In MainViewController.h:

```
@class SomeClass;

@interface MainViewController : UIViewController {
        SomeObject *someInformation;
        SomeClass *someInstance;
}
@property (nonatomic, strong) SomeClass *someInstance;

-(void)doSomething:(id)sender;
@end
```

In MainViewController.m:

```
@implementation MainViewController
@synthesize someInstance;
-(void)doSomething:(id)sender {
    //do something to someInformation
}
@end
```

In SomeClass.h:

```
@interface SomeClass : NSObject {
    UIStuff *outstuff;
}
@property (strong, nonatomic) UIStuff *outstuff;
-(void)somethingHappened:(id)sender;
@end
```

In SomeClass.m

```
@implementation SomeClass
@synthesize outStuff;
-(IBAction)somethingHappened:(id)sender {
    //call doSomething to the main class that points to this class
}
@end
```

Comment: Could you explain it better? What function would you like to call, from what class?

Comment: I want to call doSomething from SomeClass. (added that to the question)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your terminology is shaky. Classes do not "hold" other classes. In your case, instances of class MainViewController have *pointers* to objects of class SomeClass. I am not being pedantic; poor terminology such as this casts doubt on one's understanding of underlying and important concepts.

That said, SomeClass objects need a reference to a MainViewController object if you want a SomeClass object to be able to send a message to a MainViewController instance. From the code you have posted, no such reference exists. You either need to expand the SomeClass interface to store an explicit reference to a MainViewController object, or you can employ something slightly more indirect (at least conceptually) via delegation. However, because you have not provided case-specific information, our solutions will be formed lacking detail-derived insight.

Comment: True, I don't really know the exact terminology well. I'll try fix it up though. I think what I'm looking for is what you mentioned about the reference backwards. Could you care to explain how to create this reference and what I can do with it?

Comment: The main reason for doing this is to unclutter my MainViewController file. Instead of doing all the intialisations and functions in one huge class, I wanted to split them into smaller classes based on what they do.

Comment: After Coleman suggested storing a reference, I managed to come up with a way that solves this problem:
Add to SomeClass.h

    @property (strong, nonatomic) MainViewController *mainView;
    -(void)setMainView:(MainViewController *)thisMainView;

Add to SomeClass.m

    @synthesize mainView
    -(void)setMainView:(MainViewController *)thisMainView {
        mainView = thisMainView;
    }

Call setMainView in main class
then you can use [mainView doSomething] in someClass
I posted here because I can't self answer yet.